# What is an isolated beta bridge?

Tags: proteins, protein-structure

DSSP gives the letter B for a "residue in isolated β-bridge (single pair β-sheet hydrogen bond formation)", according to [Wikipedias page for secondary structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protein_secondary_structure) (and various other proper sources). Can somebody please explain what this is in some more detail please? If I google it all that comes up is pretty much the same as what wikipedia gives.

Comment: http://kinemage.biochem.duke.edu/teaching/anatax/html/anatax.2b.html

Comment: @rg255 Thanks for the link. This seems to describe beta sheets (which I am familiar with). A quick cntrl+f of "bridge" doesn't return any results? I will have a proper read in the morning if you think it will help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Kabash and Sander's paper related to DSSP (Biopolymers 1983 vol. 22 (12) pp. 2577-637) the following appears in the abstract:

*We have developed a set of simple and physically motivated criteria for secondary structure, programmed as a pattern-recognition process of hydrogen-bonded and geometrical features extracted from x-ray coordinates. Cooperative secondary structure is recognized as repeats of the elementary hydrogen-bonding patterns “turn” and “**bridge**.” Repeating turns are “helices,” repeating bridges are “ladders,” connected ladders are “sheets.”*

It seems from this that they are using the term *bridge* to mean one hydrogen bond of the type found in a beta-sheet, ladder as two protein strands joined by many hydrogen bonds, and sheets as beta-sheets — more than two protein strands joined by many hydrogen bonds. The term *beta-bridge* in the DSSP documentation (http://www.cmbi.ru.nl/dssp.html) is presumably equivalent to a *bridge* in the paper

In the DSSP files residues that are in ladders or beta-sheets are designated E, and B is used for instances where there is a single hydrogen bond. The former are very common, wheres the latter are quite rare — some proteins have none. I have prepared an image of an example for residues 74 and 79 (side-chains omitted for clarity) in a loop in the protein 1PPR.pdb (a light-harvesting protein). The other loop residues 75-78 are designated as T (turn) in the DSSP file, whereas residues 73 and 78 have no structure designation. Hence the hydrogen bond between Ser-74 and Val-79 is an isolated singleton and designated B.

[image: Beta Bridge]

Comment: Thanks for this answer David. I agree with you're reasons and I think you're correct. I appreciate you tackling the literature better than I had and the example!

Comment: You're welcome. The DSSP nomenclature is not straight-forward and some protein chemists are not too enthusiastic about some of the designations of rarer structures.